# Libgdx: How do you separate the controls from the movable object?

Tags: java, libgdx, touchpad

I'm very new to Libgdx. I have looked through many helpful tutorials, but nothing has implemented the following structure.
I've implemented a movable object that is an extension of InputAdapter, and overrides keyDown/Up to update its(object) location.
Now, I've implemented a touchPadController class that has a touchpad and knob that are visible on the screen.
Then, I added a variable that is an object of the touchPadController class.

My ultimate goal in the future is to completely separate the controls class from any movable objects/characters.

The problem:
I want to call the setInputProcessor only to the movable objects/characters, and not directly to the touchPadController class. I want the parent movable object to call its own controls.
But, I do not know where the of call for the touchPadController functions would happen??

- I tried this but it didn't work:

  `//movable object
  @Override
  public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(touchPadController);
  }
  //touchPadController
  @Override
  public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
      parent.newSpeedX = touchpad.getKnobPercentX() * Speed;
      parent.newSpeedY = touchpad.getKnobPercentY() * Speed;
      return true;
  }`

*Where should I call to the touchPadController within the parent(movable object)?

Comment: you can use "events" — in movable object(s) subscribe/unsubscribe for the event and in `touchDown` trigger its execution.

Comment: Why not let the controller move the controllee instead? Since your movable objects/characters are not handling the input themselves and forward them to your controller they are nothing but an additional proxy.

Comment: Sarge Borsch: Thank you for the suggestion. I am reading about it now. nfusion: Great! How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your controllers and your characters/entities like this:

```
public class Controller extends InputAdapter {
    private Entity _controllee;

    public void setControllee(Entity toControl) {
        _controllee = toControl;
    }

    // Override whichever InputAdapter methods you need to control your moveable objects, e.g.:
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        _controllee.newSpeedX = touchpad.getKnobPercentX() * Speed;
        _controllee.newSpeedY = touchpad.getKnobPercentY() * Speed;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally somewhere in your ApplicationListener or Screen you create an instance of the controller, attach a controllee to it via setControlle and set it as an input processor, like this:

```
Controller myController = new Controller();
myController.setControllee(/*one of your movable objects*/);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myController);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out, and let you know!